# ERROR ITMS-90725: Please update Xcode and rebuild your app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, ios11, xcode9

My current project in Swift 3.2 and Xcode 8.3 this error comes today even I have successfully uploaded to iTunes before 3 days.

> ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS
>   '10.3' SDK. All new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built
>   with the iOS '11.0' SDK or later, included in Xcode [9.0] or later.
>   Please update Xcode and rebuild your app."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's [Submitting apps to the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/):

> Starting April 2018, all new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must
>   be built with the iOS 11 SDK.

And a related (older but probably useful) [Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1806/_index.html):

> It is not practical for Xcode to force every project to build with the
>   latest SDK. For example, it may be necessary to ship an immediate
>   hot-fix version of app - without waiting until the app has been fully
>   updated for a newer SDK.
>
> But it's important to understand that using an older SDK is a
>   **temporary workaround**, not a solution. Issues preventing your app from
>   using the latest SDK should be fixed as soon as possible. It will be
>   much easier to fix these issues while the older build system is still
>   supported.
>
> **Important**: No Legacy SDK version will be supported indefinitely.

Comment: I have many faced many issues in Xcode 9.0 due to swift language version and pods.

Comment: also I have many project with the xcode 7.3 so it's mean I have to update all code ?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani I understand, but I don't make the policies :)

Comment: I know you don't make the policies I want to confirm the another way :)

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Even if it works for some projects it will be temporary. A related TN: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1806/_index.html

Comment: Can I build a project based on SDK iOS 9.3 in Xcode 7 with SDK iOS 11? by including newer SDK in Xcode 7? anyone try this?

Comment: in one word we have to update xcode right ? mine is 8.3

Comment: Yes, but What is this temporary workaround we can use?

Answer (score 2):

I met with similar problem now and **found solution** for it.
My warning looked like following:

> ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 12.0 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later.

App was built and uploaded with the newest stable XCode (**10.1**)

To check what SDK indeed you have installed, use terminal with following command:

```
xcodebuild -sdk -version
```

In response you will get printed all SDKs. In my case the problem was double SDK 12.1, but one of them was pointing on wrong path (like for *iPhoneOS12.0.sdk*):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk
```

## Solution

Solution in this case is simple.

1. Open */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs*

There you will find 2 shortcuts pointing to iPhoneOS.sdk.

2. Remove iPhoneOS12.0.sdk alias.
3. Well done.

Probably XCode takes wrong SDK based on aliases available in SDKs folder. In my case solution provided above made it working correctly without any warning.

Comment: While this may look similar, it is an entirely different issue.

Comment: Nope removing the `iPhoneOS12.0.sdk alias` Didn't worked for me. In fact the moment I removed it I got numerous Compile Time Error which were associated with the 3rd party libs.

Comment: Let me know which SDK you have available in your system. Check with  xcodebuild -sdk -version

Comment: For me this fixed my issue. I had Xcode 10.1 and was getting a rejection. Removing the iOS 12.0 alias "fixed" it for me

Comment: This worked for me. I deleted the alias for the older SDK and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on **macOS High Sierra 10.13.4** and **Xcode 10.2.1**.

**ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 12.2 SDK. As of June 30, 2020, all apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later, included with Xcode 11 or later."**

But after update OS and Xcode according to [this documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475) its resolved. And my app successfully build and submit on appstore.

Now I use **macOS Catalina 10.15.7** and **Xcode 12.1**.