# SDK Version Issue.This app was built with the iOS 14.5 SDK

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 14.5 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 15 SDK or later, included in Xcode 13 or later.

My current version is macOs Big Sur version(11.4)
and my xcode version(12.5.1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR ITMS-90725: Please update Xcode and rebuild your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178436/error-itms-90725-please-update-xcode-and-rebuild-your-app)

Comment: same stuff you just need to update your xcode

Answer (score 5):

You need `XCode 13` to use `iOS 15 SDK`. Simply update your `XCode` and `MacOS` (if necessary), then build the app again.

After updating XCode, your iOS SDK will be automatically updated.

**Instruction for Older macOS:**

- Use this patch and upgrade your macOS https://github.com/Ben216k/Patched-Sur
- After the upgrade, you can install `XCode 13` on your older mac.
- Here you can see all the supported mac lists: https://bensova.gitbook.io/big-sur/supported-macs

Comment: I have a mid 2012 macbook pro which supports xcode 12 max. Does this mean I need to buy new macbook? :(

Comment: Don't you get any update from xcode?

Comment: Not anymore. My macbook is quite old and Apple has stopped providing Xcode 13 updates.

Comment: Please check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**Below are steps I followed to solve the same issue in the same context:**

- Upgrade macOs Big Sur -> macOs Monterey v12.4
- Update Xcode 12.x -> Xcode 13.x or later

**Note:** Upgrade could take some minutes. Hence, be patient